# How to programmatically get server's certificate and add to the truestore, and check the certificate

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

In my Android app I want to use a https connection to a **USER-SPECIFIED server** which uses a **self-signed certificate**.
Because the https server is user specified, I don't know the server's certificate before, therefore I want to:

- get the server's certificate dynamically
- add this certificate's public key to the app's trust store
- authenticate the server

I do NOT want to simply accept every self-signed certificate without the user checking the certificate

I am struggling with the first step, can anybody show me a working example with basic explications?
Any hints are appreciated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but this looks promising:

https://github.com/cesarferreira/Android-Self-Signed-SSL-certificate-example

Comment: The [trustmanager implementation](https://github.com/cesarferreira/Android-Self-Signed-SSL-certificate-example/blob/master/src/org/ssl/EasyX509TrustManager.java) does nothing but verify that the server certificate is valid in date and time, it doesn't verify that the certificate itself should be trusted. Despite what the project claims, this is not secure at all.

Comment: On 12-22-2017, the above link is broken.